# Where can I find out whether the price I've been quoted for a CSS template is competitive?

Tags: css, design

I want to get a template designed. A brand guidelines document already exists, and I've already created the HTML. I don't want any graphics or javascript, so basically there's little wiggle-room from a design point of view. It should just be a typographically strong template with a few flashes of colour from a predefined palette.

Where (online) can I find out whether the amount I've been quoted is competitive. To my mind it should only be a couple of hours work so shouldn't cost too much.

Comment: Just to make sure... Is this a plain CSS file or is it a template for a Content Management System (CMS)?

Comment: I'm seeking a single CSS file, and I'll integrate it into my CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask for quotes on a freelancing website like [elance.com](http://elance.com) and see what range of offers you get.